# Change phone number programmatically

Tags: blackberry, mobile, sms

Is there a way in BlackBerry programmatically replace the phone number with the fake one, so when the SMS, which was sent from such a phone, will be received the recipient will see in 'from' field the faked number?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its not possible. You can't show the faked number after receiving the SMS.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. This kind of thing is against the security of the blackberry and we all know that blackberry provides very high level of security.